# Python program quits silently without exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I learnt about python decorators recently, so I tried and designed a decorator like this:

```
def retry(repeat,error_return=None):
    def decorator(function):        
        def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):            
            nonlocal repeat
            while repeat>0:
                try:
                    return function(*args,**kwargs)                    
                except Exception as e:
                    repeat=repeat-1
                    print(e)
            return error_return                
        return wrapper    
    return decorator
```

If an exception occurred while executing the function decorated, no exception will be raised. And the function will be retried for certain times before the exception was printed.

I used the decorator on a simple downloader, like this:

```
@retry(3)
def download_single(url,path):
    ........

    content=requests.get(url,timeout=10).content
    with open(path,'w') as f:
        f.write(content)
    print('Downloaded'+path)

def download_all(alist):
    for url in alist:
        download_single(url,PATH)
```

Normally, and as I have expected, it should work like this:
[image: The exception is skipped with error information printed]

However, in some cases, the program just stops running after an exception is printed:
[image: with only >>> left]

So why on earth does it stop by itself?? (The url list has more than 1000 elements, and it stopped at 37)

And this had happened many times, on different elements. So it is not the problem of a certain url.

And the it is the same problem when i run the program directly from console. So it is not because IDLE either.
[image: run in cmd]

Is it a problem with the decorator, or the downloader?
It only quits in this way right after an exception, so I think the exception caused the silent quit.
Has anyone met similar cases before?

Comment: Does it happen to you after 3 retries?

Comment: Do you mean it stops after printing the exception only once?

Comment: yes, only once, with one retry, one printed exception message, not 3

Comment: Why are you using `except Exception` like that?

Comment: @stasto Dont see anything wrong with the decorator. Maybe post your main code with a sample url??

Comment: Does your program quit after having printed an exception 3 times *in total* (i.e. not per URL)? In any case we need to see more than just the decorator function, i.e. the code that uses these functions. Please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your program prints 3 exceptions *in total*, i.e. not per URL. This is because you declare `repeat` as `nonlocal` and modify that variable. The wrapper defines a closure over this name (`repeat`), so for each function call you access the very same object. This mean whenever you call `download_single` and it fails it will modify the very same `repeat` object. So this gives a total of 3 retries for the whole program, instead of per URL. Then `repeat` is zero and the `wrapper` just doesn't do any work anymore (it directly returns `error_return`). This means your program doesn't quit prematurely but it exhausts the list of all files without doing any work beyond the third timeout.

Instead you can just loop over `range(repeat)` inside the wrapper:

```
for __ in range(repeat):
    try:
        return function(*args,**kwargs)                    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```